# Обновление таблицы, после добавления записи

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

Изучая Entity Framework и WPF, зашел в тупик. Делал так же как в этот статье http://ferrum-box.blogspot.ru/2012/03/entity-framework-wpf.html

Но вот вопросы:

1. Как мне сделать чтобы при добавлении записи обновлялась таблица ?
2. Как мне в таблице, где у меня есть ComboBox, заполнить его данными из таблицы справочника ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.В разметке окна указано, что нужно связать свойство `Seminars` контекста данных, коим здесь является объект `MainWindowViewModel`, со свойством `ItemSource`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Seminars}" .../>

public ObservableCollection<Seminar> Seminars { get; private set; }
```

За сценой в это время создается объект представления (`ICollectionView`), который и отображается пользователю. Но в данном случае, мы о нём можем даже не догадываться (не нужен он нам пока). Главное, что при связывании с коллекцией `ObservableCollection` объект представления (а следовательно и `DataGrid`) следит за изменениями в коллекции и при добавлении нового элемента в коллекцию `Seminars` должно автоматически произойти и обновление сетки таблицы. А вот за отслеживание изменений свойств самих семинаров отвечает в данном случае EF, реализующий в объектах `Seminar` интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
Таким образом, если вы все сделали верно, ваша команда Добавить должна вносить новые записи в связанную коллекцию `Seminars`, и новые строки должны появляться автоматически.

2.Если вам просто нужен список выбора значений (чтобы оградить пользователя от ошибок) то достаточно прописать в модели представления `MainWindowViewModel` список этих значений и связать с источником строк в `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

```
   <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Тема" ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Title}"  />
         ...
      </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Т.о. колонка выбора связывается с источником строк. Также указывается в какое свойство семинара вносить выбранную тему.
Свойство Темы:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
...

public IEnumerable<string> Themes
{ 
   get 
      {
         return new List<string> {"Алгебра","Физика"};//Можно вернуть любой список 
                       //(в данном случае строк с темами) для связывания.
      } 
}
...
}
```

**Upd.**
Реализация класса Seminar. Здесь только одно свойство, чтобы показать суть. При установке свойства, выполняется метод, который зажигает событие с указанным именем свойства.

```
public class Seminar
{
   public string Title
   {
      get
      {
        return _title;
      }
      set
      {
        _title = Value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
      } 
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
   }
}
```

Во многих MVVM-фреймворках есть базовый класс, который реализует этот интерфейс. Он обычно называется либо `ObservableObject`, либо `ViewModelBase`. И в них есть соответствующий метод вызова события (`NotifyPropertyChanged`, например).

Upd2. Привел пример к версии .net 4.0

Comment: Как мне реализовать INotifyPropertyChanged?
Не могу найти нормальной документации по этому поводу на русском. буду очень рад если вы мне напишите

Comment: >Не могу найти нормальной документации по этому поводу на русском

@Пандакун,   плохо [ищете][1]


  [1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=inotifypropertychanged+&oq=inotifypropertychanged+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6553j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#lr=lang_ru&newwindow=1&q=inotifypropertychanged&tbs=lr:lang_1ru

Comment: @Pleshkov Ivan, ссылка никуда не ведет.

Comment: @Пандакун, то не моя

Comment: @Pleshkov Ivan, студия говорит мне что не знает такой CallerMemberName.

и ComboBox не заполняется по прежнему

Comment: @Пандакун, Значит вы используете .net 4.0. в этом случае сигнатура метода будет без именованных свойств, введенных в 4.5.
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName). Если в остальном ответ принят, прошу отметить его как верный.

Comment: @Pleshkov Ivan, справочник не заполняется в Combobox.
Делаю как вы и написали но, в моём случае беру даные из таблицы (она не пустая) :
var category = from db in _dataContext.category select db.name;
Но Combobox все равно пустой.

Comment: @Пандакун, посмотреть бы проект... Все должно быть верно и работать... Linq использует отложенное применение, поэтому попробуйте его инициализировать сразу, например так: var category = (from db in _dataContext.category select db.name).ToList(); В дебаге сразу увидите, проблема ли с данными, или вы в связывании напутали.